# Get most inner nested JSON field in Java

Tags: java, json

I need to update a JSONObject only having the part of json which has been updated and not the complete json. How can I update it without losing all the other fields? I'm looking for a generalized function that works with all types of JSONObjects.

Here's an example:

Original JSON:

```
{
        "title": "Lamp",
        "events": {
            "overheating": {
                "data": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "forms": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://www.lamp.com/oh",
                        "subprotocol": "longpoll"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "actions": {
            "toggle": {
                "forms": [
                    {
                        "href": "https://lampione.it/toggle"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "@context": "https://www.w3.org/2019/wot/td/v1",
        "security": [
            "basic_sc"
        ],
        "properties": {},
        "securityDefinitions": {
            "basic_sc": {
                "in": "header",
                "scheme": "basic"
            }
        },
        "id": "urn:uuid:8c426e18-f579-42b1-a3c9-7aa9c86fbacf"
    }
```

Update input:

```
{"events":{"overheating":{"forms":[{"href":"https://lampada.it/oh","subprotocol":"longpoll"}]}}}
```

In this case the only thing that changes is the "href" field but if I replaced events field I would lose the "data" field.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why replace the `"events"` field at all? Simply retrieve the json object ("events" -> "forms"[0]) that you're attempting to modify, and then modify it. An `Object` held as a value in a map or list doesn't need to be put back into the map (or list) after modifying it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Rogue. I'm not retrieving the href field in that way because this is just an example and in a generalized case I wouldn't be able to tell which was the modified field.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "wouldn't be able to tell", can you provide an example that demonstrates this? Even real data is fine if it shows the behavior you're attempting to explain. In most of these json libs, a `JSONObject` is a `Map<String, Object>`. So you could very well `obj1.putAll(obj2);` to write in the key/value pairs from `obj2` into `obj1`, without losing anything from `obj1`. You _will_ need to walk the tree while doing this, so if you find another `Map` or `List` in your objects, then you repeat the steps for that subcollection.

Comment: @Rogue I mean that I get my 'update input' from a function and everytime it can be something different, so I'm not able to tell how much the updated field will be "nested" in my JSONObject -> I'm not able to tell how many iteration in the keys I will have to do. I don't know if this answers your question, the example I provided is made of real data.

Comment: You'll need rules for updating three things: `Map<String, Object>`, `List<Object>` and `Object` (in json terms: `{}`, `[]`, or scalars). Based on each object in the maps or lists, you'll have to call one of those rules. Scalars are the ones that write, and maps define an area that needs updating. That leaves deciding how a list input works (does it append, or replace similar objects? Do you keep some notion of "keys" for these objects e.g. href, for lookup purposes?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution in Java, using the suggestions i got from @Mel Habip and @Rogue.
Before using it, test it since some errors may not be handled in the way you want.
It is a recursive function that stops when one of the given inputs is not a JSONObject (that means it has reached the most "nested" field).

```
public static Object specialMerger(Object original, Object change) throws JSONException {
    if (original == null) {
        return change;
    }

    if (original instanceof JSONObject && change instanceof JSONObject) {
        JSONObject originalObj = (JSONObject) original;
        JSONObject changeObj = (JSONObject) change;
        JSONObject merged = new JSONObject(originalObj.toString());

        Iterator<String> keys = changeObj.keys();

        while (keys.hasNext()) {
            String key = keys.next();
            if (originalObj.has(key)) {
                merged.put(key, specialMerger(originalObj.get(key), changeObj.get(key)));
            } else {
                merged.put(key, changeObj.get(key));
            }
        }
        return merged;
    } else {
        return change;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider the following function:

```js
function specialMerger(original, change) {
    if (typeof original !== 'object' || typeof change !== 'object') {
      return change; // If either is not an object, return the change value.
    }
  
    const merged = { ...original };
  
    for (const key in change) {
      if (change.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (original.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          // If the key exists in both objects, recursively merge them.
          merged[key] = specialMerger(original[key], change[key]);
        } else {
          // If the key doesn't exist in the original object, add it.
          merged[key] = change[key];
        }
      }
    }
  
    return merged;
  }
```

We use the `for ... in` loop to iterate over the keys in a hash or the indexes in an array. This relies of the pass-by-reference property of objects.

We also use recursion to go as "deep" as we need to, where we recurse if the level we're at is still an object/array.

Comment: The OP posted about Java, not Javascript. `JSONObject` is a good hint: that's the name of `{...}` for several Java JSON libraries.

Comment: Thanks for your idea, I was thinking about recursion too. I will try to implement this in Java.